# Is it possible to encrypt data until a specified date in time?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I was wondering if there is a way to encrypt some data with an algorithm in a way that no one could decrypt that data until a specified date, say `2014/05/16`.

When I thought about it myself, I came up with answer "No", but I thought there might be an approach I had not considered.

Comment: just like a time-bomb, eh? How can data be intelligent to decrypt itself?

Comment: This is why I asked, I know data cannot be intelligent but maybe algorithms can, or maybe a clever solution...

Comment: And who's clock do you trust to determine that the decrypt date has been reached?

Comment: @mbeckish Hmmmm good point. Idk maybe my own clock! In the day of encryption.

Comment: @AramAlipoor - If you are assuming the existence of a trusted central server that has to communicate with any other servers storing the encrypted data to tell them it is now time to decrypt, then why not just have the central server send the decryption key out when it is time to decrypt?

Comment: @mbeckish Yes it is possible. Its kinda like the solution `Eric J` has provided. The only problem is that I was looking for a solution where there's no need for anything than the encrypted data itself.

Comment: @AramAlipoor - But you just said that isn't all you will need.  You also need a trusted central server to keep track of the time (so nobody could set their own clock ahead to decrypt early).  And if you have a central server, that means you also have communication between the central server and the client servers that hold the data.  Which means you have some kind of program running on the client servers to listen for the signal from the central server.

Comment: You could use a timelock puzzle, which requires a certain amount of work. But you won't be able to hit a precise target date.

Comment: I would also suggest using some kind of proof-of-work problem that would take on average x amount of time (x being the time until the open date), and either have a public server work on computing it or allow anyone to just compute it themselves, taking x amount of time from the start of the computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem lies in how the algorithm would determine what exactly the current date is.

Any software must run on hardware that provides the current date, and it is generally trivial to alter that date.  Even network-based time protocols are not especially hard to spoof.

The only solution I see is to release the key on that date.  The key release would have to be manual or using a trusted automated process with trusted time source.

Comment: Good solution, so simple and working. But In face I was looking for a solution where there's no need for anything other than encrypted data itself, to be able to decrypt it back.

Comment: @NikBougalis: The key release would have to be manual or using a trusted automated process with trusted time source.  Updated answer to make that clear.

Comment: @NikBougalis By releasing the key on that date! It needs a key-keeper being safe and alive, but BTW its a solution. Isn't it?

Comment: @AramAlipoor you said you wanted a solution that didn't include anything other than the encrypted data itself. The key would qualify as data other than the encrypted data itself.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously it can't be done as an algorithm. But there are some services like http://www.tellyoulater.com/ that publish private keys in predetermined moments of time.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If such an algorithm existed, the implications for the way our universe works would get physicists puzzled. It would mean a universe has a central clock available from anywhere by performing some computations as described below:

You could encrypt a million messages, one for every day since tomorrow (as release date) and get such a clock, purely data-based one. Want to know what date it is? Just decrypt the messages from the first one until you get stuck. The last decrypteable message determines the current date.

I think that the existence of such central clock would falsify the relativity theory (but I am not sure of that.)

Comment: We may preserve causality in this case by instead approaching the problem as "how can we make an encryption expire after a certain amount of time?" and assume we are talking about proper time; that is, time reckoned by the reference frame of the physical storage of the data files.

Answer (score 0):

Use traditional crypto and publish the key on the target date.